# split rows into table with different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I have a table with an array of strings like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
"Continent": "Europe", "Nation": "Italy", "City": "Rome"
"Continent": "Asia", "Nation": "China", "City": "Beijing"
"Continent": "Europe", "Nation": "France", "City": "Paris"
"Continent": "Africa", "Nation": "Tunisia", "City": "Tunis"
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And I would like to sort this out like:

```
ID | CONTINENT  |  NATION | CITY
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Africa     |  Tunisia| Tunis
2  | Europe     |  Italy  | Rome
3  | Europe     |  France | Paris
4  | Asia       |  China  | Beijing
```

How can I do that in POSTGRESQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string values are close to being JSONs. Cast it to `json` by enclosing them with `{}` and simply use the `->>` operator to extract individual elements as columns.

```
with js as
(
select  ('{'||str||'}')::json as j from t
) select j->>'Continent' as Continent,
         j->>'Nation'  as Nation,
         j->>'City' as City FROM js;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9e08c6485c77bdeff6835c4b05af7196)

Answer (score 0):

This is much less elegant than the accepted answer, but in the interest of sharing alternatives:

```
select
  row_number() over (partition by 1) as id,
  substring ((regexp_split_to_array (rowdata, ','))[1] from ': "(.+)"$') as Continent,
  substring ((regexp_split_to_array (rowdata, ','))[2] from ': "(.+)"$') as Nation,
  substring ((regexp_split_to_array (rowdata, ','))[3] from ': "(.+)"$') as City
from t1
```